# How does the canonization method of RDKit operate when valence is exceeded?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds, cheminformatics

RDKit's canonization method[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.5b00543) allows nitrogen to bond with 3 hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom

```python
>>> mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('[NH3]=[O]')
>>> Chem.rdmolfiles.MolToSmiles(mol, allHsExplicit=True, allBondsExplicit=True)
[NH3+]-[O-]
```

but not with two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen

```python
>>> mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('[NH2]=[O]')
>>> Chem.rdmolfiles.MolToSmiles(mol, allHsExplicit=True, allBondsExplicit=True)
Explicit valence for atom # 0 N, 4, is greater than permitted
```

Is it taking into account the morphology of the atom and bonds, not just its valence? Does the first one represent a stable compound, but not the second?

Comment: It's not exceeding, more like the opposite. Your second thing is a hydroxylamine radical.

Comment: This is probably a better question for either the rdkit e-mail list or the [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/rdkit/rdkit/discussions)

Comment: @Mithoron but, how can this be predicted for a given compound? for example, `[C]=[N]#[N] > [C]=[N+]=[N-]`, is it a property that only affects nitrogen?